# r - Cannot allocate vector size of 96.2GiB

Tags: r, arrays, memory, vector

So I am trying to use a lot of netcdf data for a project I am working on. This requires me to loop through approximately 288 files, extract temperature data, average this and then plot it. However, I am new to R and feel as though the method I am using is incredibly inefficient.

Note that this method works fine when I use 10 files. Intuitively I know that this is going to be very slow but my lack of R knowledge is preventing me from making it more efficient.

```
setwd('path')
#Picks out files that start with grid_T
temp = list.files(pattern='grid_T*')

#Opens all files and stores each in a list
myfiles = lapply(temp,nc_open)

#Creates empty temperature array with 4 dimensions to store temperature data (temperature data for each day is 1442x398x75)
temperature <- array(dim=c(1442,398,75,length(myfiles)))

#Loops through each file and pulls out temperature data and closes when done.
for (i in 1:length(myfiles)){
  temperature[,,,i] <- ncvar_get(myfiles[[i]],"votemper")
  cat("File", i,"temperature extracted\n")
  nc_close(myfiles[[i]])
}
```

After some time this returns the error

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 92.4 Gb

I can think of a couple of solutions but cannot seem to implement them:

1. In the extraction loop, open each file, extract the data, then close the file instead of opening all files first (these files don't just contain temperature, they also contain many other variables)
2. I don't actually need every entry. I only need the entries temperature[940:1009,151:323,1]. So if there were a way to extract just this it would considerably cut down the number of operations.

Comment: Not clear from your question what average you want.  Could be e.g. 1) global average at each time point for each file; 2) time-average for whole datset for each file; 3) average across all files for each cell per time slice; etc... Please clarify exactly what you need to get and plot, otherwise impossible to give an efficient solution.  BTW usually majes sense to use `raster` or `terra` or `stars` for memory-safe calculations on large rasters.

Comment: As @dww says please actually tell us what your code is doing. Don’t assume someone has the time to go through it and figure it out for themselves

Comment: I only included the part which was causing the error - which is the title of the post. See edit for the rest of my code, which works as intended. I said in my post the goal of my code but I wasn't having problems with the averaging or plotting parts, only the extraction.

Comment: I'm not familiar with netcdf, but probably the memory is still reserved after connection is closed, and this adds up. Have you tried `1:2`, `1:3`, before using the entire `1:length()`, to see how long it works? You could try to add `gc()` as last line in your loop, maybe it helps.

Comment: I included the code based on @dww and Roberts comments, thank you for rollback. I have just tried conducting a different type of approach, similar to what I mentioned in points 1 and 2. I think by opening and slicing each file within the loop I am not trying to edit one large 1442x398x75xlength(myfiles) array - which was the cause of the issue.

Comment: Switch to Linux and use [awk](https://www.howtogeek.com/562941/how-to-use-the-awk-command-on-linux/) to select just the columns you need _before_ you load it into R. here another example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164934

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this to open one file at a time

```
# list of file names
temp = list.files(pattern='grid_T*')
temperature <- array(dim=c(1442,398,75,length(temp)))

for (i in 1:length(temp)){
    # open ith file
    nc_file <- nc_open(temp[i])
    
    # do whatever
    temperature[,,,i] <- ncvar_get(nc_file,"votemper")
    cat("File", i,"temperature extracted\n")

    # close file
    nc_close(nc_file)
}
```

Comment: I believe this will overwrite each array. Ideally I would like to be able to store value nc_data holds to perform calculations. Thank you.

Comment: I was just showing some sample code to open and close one file at a time within the loop. You could still keep the temperature array you were using and update it inside the loop. (see edit)